# How to make logstash to run once in a day and stop automatically after the job is done

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I would like to develope a tool which needs to process different log files and provide some output "only one time a day". I could NOT find out online a way to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

logstash does not have a batch mode.  You would need to write a wrapper script to kill it off when it was finished.

Answer (score 0):

you would like to use exec plugin of logstash. visiting the web "https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html#plugins-inputs-exec-interval"

the "interval" configuration options could help you,Interval to run the command. Value is in seconds.

Comment: exec plugin is to execute some commands from within logstash. I want the logstash itself to be started and stopped after logstash is done with its work, once in a day(for example).

Answer (score 0):

Logstash **can** run in batch mode (v2.3.4). Simply omit the word "agent" in the command line parameters, and pipe some output into the stdin input filter like this:

```
cat /var/log/somelog | logstash -e 'input { stdin {} } output { elasticsearch {} }'
```

You will probably need to add an extra field to specify the original filename so you can query the data later on.

NOTE: The --help text for the logstash executable does not specify 'agent' as optional, but the the [example from the official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/first-event.html) omits the word 'agent'.

Comment: This won't process a list of files, which is what the user wanted.  You don't get a registry, etc...

Comment: Well it does have a "batch mode", I have corrected this common misconception for people asking this question. However, yes you probably will need a wrapper script as well to make it do what you want. And yes you lose the registry functionality.